# How to create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame using pandas.cut method?

Tags: pandas

I have a column with house prices that looks like this:

```
0          0.0
1    1480000.0
2    1035000.0
3          0.0
4    1465000.0
5     850000.0
6    1600000.0
7          0.0
8          0.0
9          0.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

and I want to create a new column called data['PriceRanges'] which sets each price in a given range. This is what my code looks like:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv")
data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

for i in range(0, 12000000, 50000):
    bins = np.array(i)
    labels = np.array(str(i))


data['PriceRange'] = pd.cut(data.Price, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True)
```

And I get this Error message:
TypeError: len() of unsized object

I've been trying different approaches and seem to be stuck here. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks, 
Hugo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem you overwrite `bins` and `labels` in loop, so there is only last value.

```
for i in range(0, 12000000, 50000):
    bins = np.array(i)
    labels = np.array(str(i))

print (bins)
11950000

print (labels)
11950000
```

There is no necessary loop, only instead `range` use `numpy` alternative [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and for labels create ranges. Last add parameter `include_lowest=True` to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for include first value of `bins` (`0`) to first group.

```
bins = np.arange(0, 12000000, 50000)
labels = ['{} - {}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
#correct first value 
labels[0] = '0 - 50000'
print (labels[:10])
['0 - 50000', '50001 - 100000', '100001 - 150000', '150001 - 200000', 
 '200001 - 250000', '250001 - 300000', '300001 - 350000', '350001 - 400000', 
 '400001 - 450000', '450001 - 500000']

data['PriceRange'] = pd.cut(data.Price, 
                            bins=bins, 
                            labels=labels, 
                            right=True, 
                            include_lowest=True)
print (data)
       Price         PriceRange
0        0.0          0 - 50000
1  1480000.0  1450001 - 1500000
2  1035000.0  1000001 - 1050000
3        0.0          0 - 50000
4  1465000.0  1450001 - 1500000
5   850000.0    800001 - 850000
6  1600000.0  1550001 - 1600000
7        0.0          0 - 50000
8        0.0          0 - 50000
9        0.0          0 - 50000
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much Jezrael! I will still need some time to fully understand how your "labels" line of code works but I get an idea. Thanks again!